# What is pseudodiagonality in matrix/tensor?

Tags: matrices, svd

**What is the difference between diagonality and pseudodiagonality? Does this apply to tensor too?**

[image: https://www.math.uzh.ch/fileadmin/math/preprints/06_11.pdf]
https://www.math.uzh.ch/fileadmin/math/preprints/06_11.pdf

Comment: I assume it's that "diagonal" usually only applies to square matrices.

Comment: That sounds reasonable